# How to modify variable attributes in JuMP?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, gurobi, julia-jump, mixed-integer-programming

I'm using Julia+JuMP and Gurobi to solve a MIP. Is it possible to modify variable attributes like [BranchingPriority](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.0/refman/branchpriority.html)?

So far, I only found methods in the documentation to modify model parameters. The only variable related modifications that seem to be possible are setting lower and upper bounds.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In most cases (but not all) your own fixed branching priority will not beat just letting Gurobi handle this. You can quickly check by exporting an LP or mps file and writing an ORD file.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to these ORD files. I didn't know they existed.